# How to rewrite Rails associations without separate queries (looping through them again)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

Running into some performance issues with the following code (stripped out irrelevant parts).

This is the CardsController#index code:

```
def index
  cards = cards.paginate(page: index_params[:page], per_page: limit)

  # Assign bumped attribute
  cards.each do |card|
    if current_user
      card.bumped = card.bump_by?(current_user)
      card.bump = card.get_bump(current_user)
    else
      card.bumped = false
      card.bump = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Card.rb:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cardable, polymorphic: true, touch: true
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :card_comments, autosave: true
  has_many :card_bumps
  has_many :card_bumpers, through: :card_bumps, class_name: 'User', source: :user

  def bump_by?(user)
    self.card_bumpers.include? user
  end

  def get_bump(user)
    CardBump.find_by(user_id: user.id, card_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

How can I avoid and optimize the second loop on each card where I do the associations of `card.bumped` and `card.bump` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just eager load the CardBump with Card? Something like `CardBump.includes(:card_bumps)`? So, you would not need to use the loop in controller at all. And you can loop through the `cards` in your view and identify whether the card is bumped or not by checking if the CardBump for that card exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model level, since the method bump_by? equals to bump existence, so

```
card.bumped = !card.bump.empty?
```

So the whole includes check in method bump_by? can be avoided, which in turn avoid fetching all associated bumps.

Comment: In the solution above, if the card size is N, you need to make N extra SQL queries to check if current_user bumps on each card or not; To further optimize the logic,  you can fetch all cards current_user have bumped , notated as M, then M intersect with N (M x N) are the cards current_user bumped. total SQL query number is 2, which is a constant, much faster : )

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would optimize your controller code a little and would update all cards with a single query if `current_user` is not present:

```
def index
  cards = cards.paginate(page: index_params[:page], per_page: limit)

  # Assign bumped attribute
  if current_user
    cards.each do |card|
      card.bump = card.get_bump(current_user)
      card.bumped = card.bump_by?(current_user)
    end
  else
    cards.update_all(bump: nil, bumped: false)
  end
end
```

There is also a possibility to optimize model code:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cardable, polymorphic: true, touch: true
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :card_comments, autosave: true
  has_many :card_bumps
  has_many :card_bumpers, through: :card_bumps, class_name: 'User', source: :user

  def bump_by?(user)
    # use #exists? to check whether a record is present in the database.
    # This will make a `SELECT 1 as count...` query and,
    # therefore, perform a lookup on database level.
    # #include? in opposite will load ALL associated items from DB, 
    # turn them into a ruby objects array and perform a lookup in the 
    # obtained array which is much slower than simple lookup performed by #exists?
    get_bump(user) == user || self.card_bumpers.exists?(user.id)
  end

  def get_bump(user)
    @_bump ||= self.card_bumpers.find_by(user_id: user.id)
  end
end
```

Since `Card#get_bump` is also looking in `card_bumpers` association we can memorize its result and later use memorized value in `Card#bump_by?` without hitting database again. If there is no memorized value then fast check for record existence will be performed by a database.

Notice, that I changed lines order in controller to get benefit of memorizing:

```
card.bump = card.get_bump(current_user)
card.bumped = card.bump_by?(current_user)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! 

Since 'bump' and 'bumped' are not database attributes, this won't work and I'll just have to run the regular set to nil:
cards.update_all(bump: nil, bumped: false)